# Need a string with a $ in powershell inside ' '

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a PS script to find a share named C$$ but PS is interpreting the $ sign and I want to pass it into the filter.
Normally \ stops this but after googling I cant get a working solution.

```
$string = "Name='C\$\$'"
Write-Host $string
get-wmiobject -Class Win32_share -filter $string
```

The write host returns Name='C\$\$'
I need it to return C$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the backtick to escape characters in a string.

```
$string = "Name='C`$`$'"
```

That should return `Name='C$$'`

Comment: Also probably worth noting that if you use single quotes you don't have to escape dollar signs. If your internal quotes can be double quotes then this may be simpler: `$string = 'Name="C$$"'`

Comment: I thought about that, but if there were any cmdlets or if this was all being passed to another script, we may have needed to keep an eye on using single or double quotes.  Although that doesn't apply with `Get-WMIObject` I thought it might be a more quality answer to keep OP's syntax as similar as possible.

Answer (score 4):

There's several ways to do this.  Note in the first one that you only need to escape the first `$`.

```
$string = "Name='C`$$'"
$string = "Name='C$$'"
$string = 'Name=''C$$'''
$string = "Name='C{0}'" -f '$$'
$string = @'
Name='C$$'
'@
$string = @"
Name='C`$$'
"@
```